# jQuery validate input type checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'am stoked at a basic task. I want to check if a checkbox i checked or not using jQuery.

The problem is that the if condition is being executed no matter its checked or not.

What am I doing wrong?

```
($('#betingelser').prop('checked', false)){
    console.log("checked if");
    isValid = false;
    result += 'Venligst accepter betingelserne<br>';        
}
```

Thanks for your time

Thar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having correct condition in if part. you are setting the value as false by using `$('#betingelser').prop('checked', false)` in it. To check whether checkbox is check use:

```
if($('#betingelser').is(':checked')){
   //rest code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing `false` as the second argument, you're actually telling the checkbox to check itself. Just delete this second argument and it should work fine.